# Return data and success/error message via AJAX

Tags: php, jquery

I am creating some functionality whereby upon submitting a form, a success message is displayed and the updated details are fetched and displayed on the page, via AJAX.

Controller:

```
public function updateAction()
{
    $query="my query"

    if(mysql_query($query))
    {
        echo "Your changes have been saved successfully";

        $customer=Customer::getDetails($_POST['cust_id']);

        include('application/view/admin/customer/_view.php');
    }
    else
    {
        echo "There was a problem saving your changes";
    }
}
```

View:

```
$('#update-customer-form').submit(function(){
    $.ajax({
        url: 'admin/customer/update',
        type: 'POST',
        data: $(this).serialize(),
        success: function(result){
            alert(result);
            $('#details').html(result);
        }
    });

    return false;
});
```

What I want to do is pass the success message, as well as the HTML output from the _view.php file if the record is saved successfully. Otherwise, just an error message is displayed. How can I do this?

EDIT: Is there any way to do this other than using json_encode()? The problem I am having is including the PHP file in my json_encode().

Comment: What is it doing right now? your jQuery code looks good, other than you are missing an error callback. `error: function(...){...}`

Comment: At the moment, the alert is outputting the HTML output.

Comment: and then after the alert, the html gets appended to the `#details` element?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Return a json object with two attributes:

```
{ "success": "true", "markup":"<div>markup goes here</div>"  }
```

Remember to encode quotes in the markup.

```
success: function(result){
        if (result.success=='true') {
            $('#details').html(result.markup);
        }
    }
```

Comment: +1. Returning json or xml is the sensible option. @GSTAR the php method you're looking for is [json_encode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php)

Comment: Cheers. How do I put my `include()` statement in the json_encode()?